# You must specify one of `href`, `id`, `profile_id` or `name`

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I dont know what could be wrong. I constantly receive this messages on my website when I'm logged as an administrator.

I'm using this OG Tags

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.soychile.cl/imagenes/soychile-avatar.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="Acto de aniversario del Golpe: tres candidatos presidenciales han confirmado su asistencia | soychile.cl"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.soychile.cl/Santiago/Deportes/2013/09/03/197812/Aniversario-del-Golpe-tres-candidatos-presidenciales-han-confirmado-su-asistencia.aspx" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Evelyn Matthei, Ricardo Israel y Alfredo Sfeir aceptaron la invitaci&#243;n del Gobierno. Rechazaron  Michelle Bachelet, Marcel Claude, Tom&#225;s Jocelyn-Holt y Roxana Miranda. Franco Parisi est&#225; en duda." />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="number" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="number" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="number" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="article:author" content="http://www.soychile.cl/" />
<meta property="article:tag" content="Acto de aniversario del Golpe: tres candidatos presidenciales han confirmado su asistencia | soychile.cl"/>
<meta property="article:tag" content="Evelyn Matthei, Ricardo Israel y Alfredo Sfeir aceptaron la invitaci&#243;n del Gobierno. Rechazaron  Michelle Bachelet, Marcel Claude, Tom&#225;s Jocelyn-Holt y Roxana Miranda. Franco Parisi est&#225; en duda." />
<meta property="article:tag" content="soychilecl" />
```

But It doesnt show any error when I'm not logged as admin

Comment: Well, the [debug tool shows no errors](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.soychile.cl%2FSantiago%2FDeportes%2F2013%2F09%2F03%2F197812%2FAniversario-del-Golpe-tres-candidatos-presidenciales-han-confirmado-su-asistencia.aspx). What actually displays these errors, some Facebook plugin you embedded? Are you sure those meta tags get rendered when you are logged in as admin?

Comment: Yeah, that's what worries me, because debugger shows me no errors and it only happens when I'm logged as administrator. I'm using Facebook Comments Plugin.